# Select values from an array and map to some strings such that same string always gets the same value and with minimum no. of repetitions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I have a fixed size array in JavaScript with certain color codes:

```
var colorArray = ["#2476B4","#97DD8F","#C7C7C7","#ADC9E7","#D42A27","#C2A091","#BFBB23","#FF9895","#E377C2","#DCD892","#FDBB79","#F3B8D2","#18BDCE","#C7B2D0","#A4DAE4"];
```

I want to assign these to certain strings. There are two requirements:

1. If the no. of strings is less than the no. of available colors than the color should not be repeated. And if the no. of strings is more then as minimum repetition as possible.
2. Each time a string appears the same color should be assigned to it.

Currently I am generating hash for the strings and taking modulo of that hash with the size of my array. This gives me the same color every time for the same string but that is causing a lot of repetition, which when the no. of strings is more is not an issue but when the no. of strings is less than the no. of available colors, makes it look very bad.

---EDIT---
Here is the code I tried:

```
 //API to generate integer of string
String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
    var hash = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        char = this.charCodeAt(i);
        hash += char;
    }
    if(hash < 0)
    {
        hash = hash * -1;
    }
    return hash;
};


//API to assign color bucket
function assignToBucket(number)
{
    var dataColor = number % colorArray .length;
    return colorArray [dataColor];
}

//API to get color for each string
function AssignColorToData(columnString)
{
    var str = columnString;
    if(str.length > 110)
    {
        str = columnString.slice(0,100) + columnString.slice(columnString.length - 10);
    }
    var hash = str.hashCode();
    return assignToBucket(hash);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: I added the code i tried in the question